# How do I edit the main implementation

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications, version

I have a web app on Google Apps Script. When I edit code and save the project I can not see the new changes on my web app.

If I create a new implementation with those new changes on the code... still I do not see changes on the web app.

Do anyone know how this new implementation works?

Comment: You need to to use Deploy/Manage Deployments and create a new version

Comment: Thank you very much, now I get it. I was creating new implementations and I had several active implementations. What I did is leaving only one active implementation, when I want to create a new implementation I just edit the active one and select "create a new version"